# Access to database table structure in a .aspx page

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0

I have a table `Software` in my database with the following columns:

```
id [key]
title
manufacturer
```

I have a dropdown list in a webform `.aspx` file. I want the items in the drop down to be `Id`, `title` and `manufacturer` but I dont want to hard-code the items.

I am going to add more columns in the database table and I want the drop down list items to always remain in sync with the table structure.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `LINQ`:

```
var columnNames = dataTable1.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().
                  Select(c => c.ColumnName).ToList();
comboBox1.DataSource = columnNames;
comboBox1.DataBind();
```